# Sorting file with 1.8 million records using script

Tags: exception, sorting, large-files, stack-dump

I am trying to remove identical lines in a file having 1.8 million records and create a new file. Using the following command:

```
sort tmp1.csv | uniq -c | sort -nr > tmp2.csv
```

Running the script creates a new file `sort.exe.stackdump` with the following information:

```
"Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at rip=00180144805
..
..
program=C:\cygwin64\bin\sort.exe, pid 6136, thread main
cs=0033 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B"
```

The script works for a small file with 10 lines. Seems like `sort.exe` cannot handle so many records. How do I work with such a large file with more than 1.8 million records? We do not have any database other than ACCESS and I was trying to do this manually in ACCESS.

Comment: Seems as if SORT.EXE (whatever that is) is using a recursive algorithm, and it's blowing the stack.  Why not import the CSV to Access, sort it in a query using an ORDER BY clause, and export to the new CSV?

Comment: 1.8 million records doesn't really say much. How large is each record (or how large is the file)?

Comment: @Dukeling, from the error message it looks like Cygwin which shouldn't have any troubles with a file like this. I'd suggest checking all the disks to make sure one isn't filling up with temporary files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following awk command seemed to be a much faster way to get rid of the uniqe values:

awk '!v[$0]++' $FILE2 > tmp.csv

where $FILE2 is the file name with duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your sort command is broken. Since the path says cygwin, i'm assuming this is GNU sort, which generally should have no problem with this task, given sufficient memory and disk space. Try playing with flags to adjust where and how much it uses the disk: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html